# error in showing image through api in carousel in flutter

Tags: android, api, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am getting the image list from API and want to show it in the carousel but due to some error, it is not happening. I have tried forEach in this and also the error handling part but nothing is working.
I am facing problems same as below link...
can anyone give me any advice or solution for the below problem...

[unable to show images through api in carousel pro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65592706/unable-to-show-images-through-api-in-carousel-pro)

please help me with this...

Comment: You'll need to post your code here.  Both the widget code and how you get your data.

Comment: in the below link i have done that once. please check there.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here => package:etroc/Screens/dashboard.dart:147:48;  Not on the HomeScreen (Unless you don't list naming your classed the same as your files).

Issue is with this method => _HomeScreenState.getalladminbanner look at the error closer.

If you can post this code I might be able to help you further.